# How do I make an batch file answer differently to a specific input?

Tags: batch-file

I already know how to make an input, but I don't know how to make the batch say something differently after a specific input.

For example : If the user put "Hamburger" in the input, then batch will say something like "correct"
But if the user says anything else, the batch will say "wrong"

Comment: [if](https://ss64.com/nt/if.html)

Answer (score 0):

Using the if statement can check "if something = something, then do something"

```
set /p userinput=
if %userinput% == Hamburger goto correct
echo Wrong
pause 
exit

:correct
echo Correct
pause
Exit
```